# Get first record from csv file using DictReader

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to get the first record as a dict from a csv file using the DictReader. I am unable to understand as the documentation only talk about iterating the reader object

```
 with open(filename, 'r') as f_in:
        # Use the csv library to set up a DictReader object.
        trip_reader = csv.DictReader(f_in)
        # Use a function on the DictReader object to read the
        # first trip from the data file and store it in a variable.
        for row in trip_reader:
                   pprint(row)
```

Is there any function to get the first record as trip_reader[0]?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? If you want to print the row in the same way as it exists in the .csv file, then use `reader` instead of `DictReader`.

Comment: What is `pprint`? Where are `city` & `first_trip` defined to be returned?

Comment: @ArneRecknagel i wanto get the first record from the reader without using the for loop.

Comment: Yeah, pstatix answered that. `csv.DictReader` implements `__iter__` and not `__getitem__`, so `next()` needs to be used to access its items instead of `[idx]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you can iterate over `trip_reader`, you can call `next()` on it to get the next (in this case, the first row):

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f_in:
    # Use the csv library to set up a DictReader object.
    trip_reader = csv.DictReader(f_in)
    # Use a function on the DictReader object to read the
    # first trip from the data file and store it in a variable.
    row = next(trip_reader)
    pprint(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get first row of a CSV without a `for` loop:

```
with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    return next(r)
```

Of course if you have a row of headers you'll have to "jump" over it:

```
with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    _ = next(r) # hold header row in throwaway variable
    return next(r)
```

The `newline=''` in the context manager is used in Python3+ (maybe later versions of Python2 as well) but for Python2.7.8 and earlier you can omit.

Comment: is `_ = next(iter)` prefereable over just `next(iter)`?

Comment: @ArneRecknagel Depends on implementation; `_` just stores them, and upon `return` the garbage collector frees the memory since they are no longer in scope. Without it, sometimes the implementation will actually send the headers to the `stdout` stream and you will see them printed. Use `_` if you don't want them to be displayed.